zero or indefinite article in a negative sentence
In a situation below, how can I say the last sentence?
We have some events every year.  One is in October or September.  One is in November or December.  One is held in April.

Please note that we don't have an event in summer.
Please note that we don't have events in summer.
Please note that we don't have any events in summer.

I cannot find information about negative sentences with indefinite articles.
Can I use "an" in such a situation?
Could you please give me example sentences and tell me in what situations I can use them?

You could also say "we have no summer events" or "we have no summer event".  You'd use the plural if you held no events of any kind during the summer, and the singular if it was no event of a particular type being discussed in context.

All of those alternatives would be acceptable. In my opinion (1) is the best option.
It appears that events are held in autumn, winter and spring, so people might expect there to be one event in summer too. It's therefore natural to refer to the non-existent summer one as an event.

Using the singular (with the indefinite article) definitely suggests that one might expect only a single event per season.
